# не хватает ... рубля/рублей

Tags: числительные, родительный-падеж

> не хватает три рубля/трёх рублей
>
> не хватает два рубля/двух рублей
>
> не хватает один рубль/одного рубля

etc.

Both seem to be commonly used in day-to-day speech. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** To reiterate, I'm not asking which of the two options is *correct*. I'm asking why  both versions can be commonly encountered. Вопрос не про норму, а про узус. Не про то что правильно, а про то, почему повседневно встречается и первый вариант.

Comment: Can you give examples of use of the first versions? I've only heard it from beggars in train stations / metro.

Comment: Well, there's really no way to give an example as it's something that would only ever be heard in speech. Though for what it's worth, "не хватает три рубля" returns 10,500 Google results whereas "не хватает трёх рублей" returns 3,460. For "не хватает два рубля" it returns 706 and for "не хватает двух рублей" — 3,710.

Comment: In Russian it is not correct to use "Не хватает один рубль (пять рубль, семь рубль и т.д. по порядку)" because second word must be declined in the genitive

Comment: @texnic, for example (from here - http://www.galya.ru/clubs/show.php?id=613556) - Cегодня в супермаркете на кассе маленький мальчик хотел взять только мороженое и конфеты “Меллер“, но ему не хватало 2 рубля, я ему их дала.

Comment: What are you asking? If you want to write a mixed question, provide both a complete Russian and English version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I've never heard "не хватает один рубль" but definitely many times heard "рубля" instead of "рублей".

To be honest, each time I'm trying to response such kind of questions, I think of "Из заметок о любительской лингвистике" [book](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6210376/). I'm not a professional linguist, neither I'm bold enough to call me even an amateur linguist. So be warned, what I'm going to say is just a hypothesis.

I do believe that the reason behind this customary declension is that in phrases like this "не хватает" can be interpreted as [transitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb), and, talking about transitive verbs [in Russian](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5), one should remember following:

> Вместо винительного падежа дополнение при переходном глаголе может
>   стоять и в родительном падеже без предлога: 1) если есть отрицательная
>   частица `не` перед переходным глаголом: понял задачу — не понял
>   задачи; читал роман — не читал романа; терять время — не терять
>   времени;

Also, it is told that:

> При определении переходности/непереходности глаголов необходимо
>   учитывать и значение существительного в форме винительного падежа —
>   оно должно называть объ­ект действия.

See, in phrases [like](http://www.ricardo.com.ua/news/economics/114082) "Украине не хватает три миллиарда для расчета за газ" (so it is not only about roubles) numeral is treated - and I'm using treated in strictly customary way))) - like noun. Moreover, "три [чего?] рубля" is treated like a noun.

To illustrate this, we can easily say - "Недостающие Украине три миллиарда придётся где-то поискать", "недостающие два рубля, он, к своей великой радости, нашёл под столом". And participle is a noun modifier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is very much what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context.
There is 6 (падеж) in russian languge:

1. Именительный (from name - имя): У тебя есть (Что?) три рубля.
2. Родительный. You may think of it just like you missing something/someone: В коробке нет (чего?) трёх рублей.
3. Дательный (From Give - Дать). Think of it just like you whant to give something to someone. It will be difficult to explane on example with "три рубля". So, there is two examples: with enlivened and unenlivened object: Рассказать (кому?) соседу. Положить деньги к остальным (чему?) трём рублям.
4. Винительный (from Blame - Винить). Think of it just like you whant to blame someone/something.  Я виню (кого?) себя. Я виню (что?) три рубля. As you can see, in case of unenlivened object, question is same as for (именительный падеж).
5. Творительный (From Make - Творить). Think of it just like you controll something: Я владею (Чем?) тремя рублями.
6. Предложный (From sentence - предложение). Think of it just like you speaking about something: Давайте поговорим (о чём?) о трёх рублях.

---

So, in your case: Не хватает одного/двух/трёх/четырёх (etc) рублей.

Comment: мне три рубля буквально сегодня не хватило, чтобы газету купить, это, стало быть, винительный? Я не подвергаю сомнению ваш ответ, я пытаюсь понять.

Comment: Если что-то произошло из-за трёх рублей, вы можете винить их. Но это не значит, что каждый раз говоря об этих трёх рублях, вам нужно ставить их в винительный падеж. Склонение существительных по падежам производится для каждого конкретного случая: "Мне сегодня не хватило трёх рублей (родительный), чтобы купить газету. Если бы не эти три рубля (именительный), всё было бы совсем иначе. Газета стоила пятьдесят три рубля (винительный), и лишь этими тремя рублями (творительный) я не обладал".

Comment: I've updated the question...

Comment: I'm trying to tell that always, but few exeptions, there is only one right solution. So, why both seem to be commonly used in day-to-day speech? There is some resons for that: 1) As I said, it depends of context. 2) russian languge provides a great namber of ways to tell what you whant. Sometimes, it's useful, but sometimes it becomes a source of mistakes. Mistakes, making everywhere, by everybody. Mistakes, becoming usual and used in day-to-day speech.

Comment: Writing absoluttely right, sometimes, is really hard task. I got "4" in russian languge (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_(education)#Russia), and tried to solve this: http://totaldict.ru/idictation/bykov/ I got 5 punctuation mistakes and 10 orfographical, and no one from my friends (all of them is well educated persons) didn't make it much better.

Answer (score 1):

The verbs *хватать*, *доставать*, *довлеть* (in its original meaning) govern nouns both in singular and in plural without changing their form (though with different meaning):

> - Мне хватило лошади // мне хватило лошадей
> - Ему недостаёт года // ему недостаёт лет
> - Ей довольно друга // ей довольно друзей

Using these words with numerals leads to a contamination, because it's not clear whether the verb should govern the noun directly or through the numeral, the end result (for the noun) being the same.

Answer (score 0):

не хватает трёх рублей, двух рублей, одного рубля

Comment: Вопрос не про норму, а про узус. Не про то что правильно, а про то, почему повседневно встречается и первый вариант.

Comment: the first variant is widely used only due to people's illiteracy. it is absolutely incorrect from the point of view of the language's rules. but nobody cares, of course

Comment: and btw, what is узус?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha узус = common usage. "У́зус (от лат. usus — применение, обычай, правило) — общепринятое носителями данного языка употребление языковых единиц (слов, устойчивых оборотов, форм, конструкций)." [Wikipedia]